# How to access data from view to model in C# & ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have classes `User` and `Role`, and I want to access to the name of the user from `Role`.

My classes are:

```
public class ShiftCalendar
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ShiftId { get; set; }
    public virtual Shift Shift { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShiftEndTime { get; set; }        

    public User ShiftManager { get; set; }
    public string ShiftManagerId { get; set; }
}

public class Shift
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }       

    public TimeSpan ShiftBeginTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ShiftEndTime { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ShiftCalendar> ShiftCalendars { get; set; }
}

public class User: IdentityUser
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ShiftCalendar> ShiftCalendars { get; set; }
}
```

I want to access to the name of the user in the `ShiftCalendar` index view, but this data is empty when I tried to show it:

The view code is:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Dal.Models.ShiftCalendar>

@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
<table>

  @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Shift.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShiftManager.FirstName) 
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShiftEndTime)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |

                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

The other values (Shift.Description, Date and EndDate) appear.

The index controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var shiftCalendars = _unitOfWork.ShiftCalendarsRepository.Get();
    return View(await shiftCalendars.ToListAsync());
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: EF or EF Core ? Try to use the `.Include(p=> p.ShiftManager)` on your query when selecting the `ShiftCalendar`

Comment: I have solved using public virtual User instead public User